# jQuery change cookie expiry from time value to session value

Tags: jquery, cookies, session-cookies

I have absolutely no knowledge of cookies...

I'm using Slidedeck on my site, and they provide a code to enable people who return to the page with the slidedeck on to display the last viewed slide instead of returning to the beginning.

However it's set for a week - what I'd like to do is change it to session based, so that when the browser closes, the cookie is no longer valid. Is that possible with this script?

I've read that if you change the expiry to 0, it'll make it session based - so I changed:

```
else {
      var expires = "0";
    }
```

But I don't think that works due to the if statement above it.

```
// The default slide to start on is 0.
  var startingSlide = 0;
  // If we find a cookie with the name that we previously saved, use it.
  if(readCookie('slideDeckDemoCurrentSlide')){
    // This overrides the default value of 0 if we find a cookie.
    startingSlide = readCookie('slideDeckDemoCurrentSlide');
  }
  var myDeck = $('.slidedeck').slidedeck({
    autoPlay: false,
    cycle: true,
    slideTransition: 'slide',
    touch: false,
    hideSpines: true,
    start: startingSlide, // tell the Deck where to start
    complete: function(deck){
      // Here we will set a cookie for one week.
      // This cookie will store the deck.current value.
      //createCookie(name,value,days)
      createCookie('slideDeckDemoCurrentSlide',deck.current,7)
    }
  });




  function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
      var date = new Date();
      date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
      var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else {
      var expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
  }

  function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
      var c = ca[i];
      while (c.charAt(0)===' '){ c = c.substring(1,c.length); }
      if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
  }

  function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
  }
```

Comment: Sessions are server based, jQuery is client based. What is your server software? PHP? ASP?

Comment: Also don't forget that closing the browser will not necessarily close the session.

Comment: My ignorance is showing through. The server side is ASP - but I'd need to stick with jQuery and incorporate it into this script.

Answer (score 1):

Session Cookies and browser Cookies have nothing in common. Especially Javascript is executed on the CLIENT so you only have access to browser cookies. You could use `.unload()` to detect if the browser was closed or the page was closed and then delete the cookie:

```
$(window).unload( function () { //delete cookie } );
```

Comment: So would I add this to the end of the script or the beginning? $(window).unload( function () { eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
  }   } );

Comment: I would add it in the $(document).ready(function(){}) section but its not really a difference where you put it !

Comment: It's killing the cookie as soon as they leave the page with the unload function. I guess I'm going to need to look at the jquery cookies plugin and attempt a rewrite of the provided script...

Comment: yeah there is a good jquery cookie plugin. Other ways of deleting the cookie is by setting the expire date beyond the actual date like 1.1.1990 which will make it invalid and the browser delets it. If this anwer helped you please accept it or upvote it

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a session cookie do not use the expires option.
This is from the official documentation of "[jquery cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)" :

> Define lifetime of the cookie. Value can be a Number which will be
>   interpreted as days from time of creation or a Date object. If
>   omitted, the cookie becomes a session cookie.

If you set the expires : 0 , then this means the cookie will not be saved at all.